# Java: Sorting a Map, Map<Long,Map<String, Data>> based on the inner map

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I am new to java and is still in the learning phase.
I have  a structure

```
Map<Long, Map<String, Data>> mapData
```

`Data` has 2 fields `time` and `distance`
and the `Map` has a time which is a `Long` field and `map` with `Identifier` and `Data`
the structure looks like this

```
{190001919 = {[1= [data1], 2=[data2], 3=[data3]}, 
190001920={[1=[data4], 2=[data5], 3=[data6]}, 
1900019121= {[1=[data7], 2=[data8], 3=[data9]}}
```

and then convert it into a map - `Map<String,List<Data>> mpData` with
`idenifier` as `key` and `values` as the values where there the identifier was the same.

like

```
{1= [data1,data4,data7], 2= [data2,data5,data8],3= [data3,data6,data9]}
```

Could some one please help me? 
Update:
With the below code, I get

```
{1= [data7,data7,data7], 2= [data8,data8,data8],3= [data9,data9,data9]}
```

instead of

```
 {1= [data1,data4,data7], 2= [data2,data5,data8],3= [data3,data6,data9]}
```

Code:

```
public static Map<Long, Map<String, Data>> listData;
public static Map<String, List<Data>> mapData;
public convertMapData(Map<Long, Map<String, Data>> array) {
        listData = new HashMap();
        listData = array;
        mapData = new HashMap<>();
        Iterator it = listData.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<Long, Map<String, Data>> pairs = (Map.Entry) it
                    .next();
            Long keyValue = pairs.getKey();
            Map inter = pairs.getValue();

            Iterator it2 = inter.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it2.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, Data> pairs_2 = (Map.Entry) it2
                        .next();
                String identifierK = pairs_2.getKey();
                Data resultV = pairs_2.getValue();
                if (!(mapData.containsKey(identifierK))) {
                    mapData.put(identifierK, new ArrayList<Data>());
                }
                mapData.get(identifierK).add(resultV);      
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Now what is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why you need `List<Map<...>>`? I guess simple `Map<...>` will be fine.

Comment: @ROhit: you are right, i dont need a List there

Comment: Would it not be simpler to expand the `Data` class to include all relevant fields (including id)? Then just have a `List<Data>` to store all of your entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Define `Map<String,List<Data>> listData = new HashMap<String, List<Data>>();`
2. Iterate over `mapData`'s values (seems you don't use the keys of that map).
3. For every value of `mapData`, which again is a map, iterate over the `entrySet`, which gives you key (a `String`, lets call it `K`) and value (a Data object, lets call it `V`) of every entry.
4. Check if your `listData` already has a key like `K` (using `containsKey()`) and if not, add one, using `listData.put(K, new ArrayList<Data>())`
5. add `V` to the list that's stored for the key: `listData.get(K).add(V)`

That's all. As Rohit Jain commented, you'll not need a list around the listData map.

Try this:

```
public Map<String, List<Data>> convert(Map<Long, Map<String, Data>> array) {
    Map<String, List<Data>> result = new HashMap<String, List<Data>>();
    for (Map<String, Data> inter : array.values()) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Data> entry : inter.entrySet()) {
            String k = entry.getKey();
            String v = entry.getValue();
            if (!result.containsKey(k)) {
                result.put(k, new ArrayList<Data>());
            }
            result.get(k).add(v);      
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the algorithm!!

Comment: one problem, when i do, `listData.get(K).add(V)`, it overwrites the old value so instead of ` {1= [data1,data4,data7], 2= [data2,data5,data8],3= [data3,data6,data9]} , i get `{1= [data7,data7,data7], 2= [data8,data8,data8],3= [data9,data9,data9]}`

Comment: i have updated the code on the orginal post. Are u able to see?

Comment: Seems like it's okay - I added a simpler version to my answer, which should work.

Comment: thanks a lot. it works :) and the problem was with the data when i was populating it.. Thanks again